# Add property to state React Redux Template

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, single-page-application

I am new to React and I started by grabbing the [ReactRedux-CSharp Visual Studio Template](https://github.com/aspnet/templating/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates/content/ReactRedux-CSharp) and am trying to add other properties to state. I have a slider on the page that I want to update the state when the position changes. The module in question is [react-rangeslider](https://github.com/whoisandy/react-rangeslider). The example says to do something like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Slider from 'react-rangeslider'

class VolumeSlider extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.state = {
      volume: 0
    }
  }

  handleOnChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      volume: value
    })
  }

  render() {
    let { volume } = this.state
    return (
      <Slider
        value={volume}
        orientation="vertical"
        onChange={this.handleOnChange}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

When I add that code, I get an error on Webpack build

> TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.

I have looked at index.d.ts (where state is declared) and am not sure what I need to do to add this. Do I need to wire up actionCreators and reducers for this one property, or is there an easier way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a TypeScript error from the Slider component.

What it says is that the `value={volume}` prop you pass is `undefined` (or `null`, or a non-numeric value), while it is strongly typed as `Number` [here](https://github.com/whoisandy/react-rangeslider#component) in the component. Can you print its value?

**Edit**: Possibly (likely) the docs are wrong and the `onChange` handler takes an event as argument, in which case you should do

```
handleOnChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    volume: event.target.value
  })
}
```

and report this to the authors.

Comment: I think the issue is binding it. If I set it to a property of the component, I see it changes, however even though the onChange fires and I can console.log and see the new value, the UI does not update with the new version

Comment: I ended up just wiring up all the redux stuff like the other examples :/

Comment: Assuming your app will grow, you will gain in the long term having set Redux anyway. But I would get rid of any component that has a wrong documentation and shaky API in the first place.